# How accurate is the plot in Netflix's show 'Orange is the New Black'?

Tags: realism, orange-is-the-new-black

So I know the premise of Netflix's *Orange is the New Black* is based on a true story, but how closely does the show follow true events? Are the actual events/goings-on in the TV story based on details within Piper Kerman' book, *Orange Is the New Black: My Year in a Women's Prison,* or is the majority of the specifics of the storyline in the show fiction?

Answer (score 3):

The show is only 'inspired by' the book, which itself should be noted is only one person's view of events (and has been called into question by certain 'participants,' such as Cleary Wolters, who is the real life Alex Vause).

While certain things did happen, such as her going to the same prison as her ex, most are made up, such as her getting back into a relationship with that ex.  I'm assuming you don't need a point-by-point comparison. :)